# After use submodule to import third part framework, how to include this framework into project?

Tags: ios, git, git-submodules

I have use pod submodule to include a third part framework `A-FRAMWORK`

so after do submodule update, this framework is downloaded.

But how to include this framework into project file automatic?

Is it possible to include by Podfile?

Comment: is it Podfile or Procfile?

Comment: What's that means? the 'A-FRAMWORK' is a framework on git.

Comment: @VishnuAtrai, and after do  'git submodule update', the 'A-FRAMWORK' downloaded in my specify folder, but I want write some command in my Project's Podfile, so that after I run 'pod install', the submodule framework can include in my project.

Comment: you will have to require or load your submodule from path

Comment: @VishnuAtrai, sorry, I don't really understand what you means or what I should do step by steps.

Comment: @VishnuAtrai  basically I solved this by found a Podfile.

Comment: And then it's included by code, not by a third part framework.